# Invalid number with strings that contains comma in oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I am trying to learn pl/sql.I created a procedure in oracle.Procedure gets input like that 3,4 but when I execute my procedure
I get invalid number error.

My procedure is :

```
 PROCEDURE Student(
  p_types             IN  VARCHAR2,
  p_istatus           OUT      INTEGER
 )
 IS     
 v_value VARCHAR2(2000);

 BEGIN   
 dbms_output.put_line (p_types);  --It prints correctly (3,4)
 SELECT discount_id into v_value FROM Student where type_id in (p_types);
END Student;
```

My error is :  `Invalid Number`

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Well, `'3,4'` is not a number.  It is a string.  The SQL expression expects a list of numbers (based on the type of `type_id`), not a string.

Comment: If you mean you are passing in a string of '3,4', that is not what you are expecting.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how can i convert to number?

Comment: What number are you trying to convert '3,4' to? It's a rhetorical question because (as has been pointed out before) 3,4 is not a number.

Comment: I wrote this a million years ago: https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/comma-separated.html